# Почему ajax не подгружается у компонента

Tags: ajax, битрикс

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему ajax не подгружается у компонента "bitrix:search.title"?
Хотя бы несколько причин.

Comment: лучше будет, если покажете как вызывается компонент. А индексация проводилась? вот из доки: `Внимание! Если компонент был добавлен в систему через обновления, то для его работы потребуется полная переиндексация. Подробнее про индексацию смотрите на странице Переиндексация.`

Comment: Переиндексация не нужна так как этот компонент есть и он переиндексирован.

Comment: Код к сожалению не могу показать. Просто хотя бы примерно подскажите. Могу описать:  На страницах сайта есть поиск, открываем и например набираем "сталь". Подрубается ajax и выдает список товаров
на главной странице не отрабатывает.

Comment: а в консоли браузера ошибок нет? и запросы сетевые идут?

Comment: Get https://bitrix.info/ba.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCKER
(anonymous) @ (index):52
(anonymous) @ (index):52
alkesta.ru/:4437 
GET https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-120475972-1 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCKER

Comment: Вот такие ошибки вывел в консоли

Comment: Вот страница на которой не работает https://alkesta.ru . Можете сами попробовать написать сталь в поиске. На этой же странице отрабатывает скрипт.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $scrolltotop.stop is not a function
    at CheckScrollToTop (template_b4874fe89ab1561d6be8a88c5a4962ba_v1.js?1623406002573592:2190)
    at template_b4874fe89ab1561d6be8a88c5a4962ba_v1.js?1623406002573592:6800
    at dispatch (jquery-2.1.3.min.js?157114123084320:3)
    at r.handle (jquery-2.1.3.min.js?157114123084320:3)

Comment: из-за этой ошибки в js может все остальное ломаться

Comment: $scrolltotop.stop(true, true).removeClass('visible'); вот эта строчка в ваших исходниках

Comment: Большое спасибо! От души в душу.